# Defining OneToMany relationship just one side of the relationship

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many, dropwizard

Hello I have the following OneToMany relationship where a Request can have many Services. I have defined the relationship on the Request as follows

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "Request")
    public class Request {

          @JsonProperty
          @OneToMany(mappedBy = "request")
          Set<Service> services;
}
```

And in the Service class

```
  Request request;
```

When I start the server, it errors out with the following message

```
! com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: BLOB/TEXT column 'request' used in key specification without a key length
```

I am not sure why it would think a request is a column with text. What have I missed in the relationship? Should the relationship be defined on both sides of the relationship?

Comment: Is the column `request` defined in a way that MySQL accepts?

Comment: hmm weird, I had to define the relation on both sides to make it work

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem with ManyToOne() Unidirectional mapping like bellow.

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "Request")
    public class Request {

   // Nothing
}

@Entity
@Table(name ="Service")
public class Service{

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "request_id", nullable= false)
    public Request request;
}
```